# Pass value from first activity to third activity into a listview overrides old value

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an app, where a user can enter a number and save to listView. The app is split into 3 activities.
The first activity is the MainActivity, which does something else. The second activity is where I enter a number and save it. The code Is below

```
public class HomeTeamScored extends Activity {

protected static EditText display;
protected static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Button addButton;
CheckBox checkBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rect_activity_home_goal_player);

    display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);


    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String task = display.getText().toString();
            adapter.add(task);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            SavePreferences();


            Intent i = new Intent(HomeTeamScored.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

protected void SavePreferences() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences data = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("saveNumber", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); ++i){
        // This assumes you only have the list items in the SharedPreferences.
        editor.putString(String.valueOf(i), adapter.getItem(i));
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

In my third activity, I retrieve the saved number.

```
public class ScoreBoardOverview extends Activity {

ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rect_activity_score_board_overview);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    loadPreferences();
}

protected void loadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences data = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("saveNumber", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    for (int i = 0;; ++i){
        final String str = data.getString(String.valueOf(i), "");
        if (!str.equals("")){
            adapter.add(str);
        } else {
            break; // Empty String means the default value was returned.
        }
    }
}
```

}

All this is working fine, and it adds a number to listView, but the problem is that it overrides the old value, were instead it should add a second row.

Anyone who can help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);


    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String task = display.getText().toString();
            adapter.add(task);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            SavePreferences();


            Intent i = new Intent(HomeTeamScored.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

here your adapter item size will be 0 when you call second activity each time. if you want to add second or third item you should write your

```
protected void loadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences data = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("saveNumber", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    for (int i = 0;; ++i){
        final String str = data.getString(String.valueOf(i), "");
        if (!str.equals("")){
            adapter.add(str);
        } else {
            break; // Empty String means the default value was returned.
        }
    }
}
```

method in second activity too. and call `loadPreferences()` after this line

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

your adapter data size will be changed.